# how to record the score in a database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a database to record and analyse data about a sports game

one of my tables will be 'matches' which records details about a match (the team ids, location, date etc) and includes the final score. I also have another table which records a specific score in a match (i.e. who scored it and the number of points) called 'scores'. My question is whether I should record the score in 'matches' or, if I want to know the score, just add up all the points in 'scores'? Is there a way such that if a 'scores' row is updated then it will recalculate the score in 'matches'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way and it is called a "trigger".  You can set up a trigger on the `scores` table so whenever a new record is inserted, the appropriate value in the `scores` table is updated.

The place to start is with the documentation on triggers, which is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

If your data is not large, then you can create a view that has the same information.  Something like:

```
create view v_matchscores as
    select m.*, sum(case s.team = m.teama then score else 0 end) as ascore,
           sum(case when s.team = m.teamb then score else 0 end) as bscore
    from matches m join
         scores s
         on m.matchid = s.matchid
    group by m.matchid
```